# JavaScript regex delimiters - how to not escape any slash? (/)

Tags: javascript, regex

Is there any way in JavaScript to use a different character than `/` (forward slash) as a delimiter in a regular expression?
Most other languages have a way of doing this.

For example, Perl:

```
 m@myregex@
```

So, in Perl, to match a string that contains the string `/tmp`, this is a valid regex, without any escape and very readable:

```
 m@/tmp@
```

Instead in JavaScript, it seems I need to write `/\/tmp/` or something like that. Are we confined to always escape "/" in JavaScript?

Comment: Since the original intention it's clearly to use a slash as normal character to be captured, so, without the need of escaping that, for better readability, I tried to add another example to make that more evident. Also, put more focus on the problem. This was needed to me, since most answers here are going in other directions, and the OP needed to comment each answer to clarify the original intention. So, the need to try to improve the answer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The short answer is No. JavaScript does not offer a native way to express a custom regex delimiter.

In the simple way of using regular expressions in JavaScript you would delimit it with `/  /`. However, also using the native constructor of [`RegExp`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp), that accepts a string as first argument, you also need to escape slashes, and twice.

The following examples are equivalent to match a string containing the value `/tmp`:

```js
// shortway, you must escape any internal '/' as '\/'
// note that you cannot change the delimiter
var re = /\/tmp/;

// constructor, you must escape any '/' twice as '\\/'
// note that you cannot express a delimiter
var re = new RegExp('\\/tmp');
```

So, in native JavaScript, regexes must have slashes escaped.

Comment: Thanks. It occurs to me that double-escaping is a MAJOR pain so I guess I'm stuck with using single escapes for the character "/" and using "/" as the delimiter. It would be great if someone wrote a library or special function to make escaping regexes in javascript easier!

Answer (score 8):

> Are we confined to just using "/" in javascript?

Not really.. you can avoid using any regex delimiter by using [`new RegExp (string)` constructor.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp)

```
var re = new RegExp (string);
```

Just keep in mind that this will require you to double escape instead of single escape.

Comment: Good answer, but I'd still like to know if I can use a different character from "/" in my syntax above. If I have to declare the regex this way, it takes more typing. I'm trying to reduce the time it takes to write regex one-liners.

Comment: @pepper you cannot. A JavaScript parser gets tied in all sorts of knots as it is with the `/` delimiter; allowing any other character would be seriously problematic.

Comment: you need to instantiate the regex with new RegExp( string ) and escape all special characters twice inside, see the solution.

Comment: This is direct answer to your question of avoiding `/` as delimiter. Your marked answer suggests using regex literal using `/.../` syntax which obviously doesn't fulfill your requirement.

Answer (score 6):

In Javascript, if you want to inline a regexp, your only option is the forwardslash delimiter: `/foo/`

As other answers note, you can also assign a regular expression to a variable using `new Regexp("foo")`.

Using multiple delimiters is definitely a Perl thing.  In Perl you can use nearly any character as a delimiter, for example with strings:

typical syntax using single quotes -- `'dipset'`

using the q function -- `q(dipset)` `q!dipset!` `q%dipset%`

Whether this produces something readable is dependent on context.. it's nice that Perl lets you do this, if the result is something that is readable.  For example, regular expressions are unreadable enough, without having a bunch of escaped backslashes inside.